# Mass update of data in table - best method?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have a query similar to the below:

```
UPDATE customers c SET AssetsTotal = f_SumAssetCosts(c.Id);
```

I'm concerned that MySQL may be looking at the entire table and placing a lock for update on the entire data set. So if this single UPDATE statement happens for millions of customers and the f_SumAssetCosts has even just a small amount of time to process, this entire process could lock the table for whole seconds, potentially minutes. This isn't desirable in a high transaction system where the customers rows may be read/update quite frequently.

First, would MySQL be placing a lock (for UPDATE/DELETE) on the entire table whilst the entire operation is running?

Second, just to confirm my knowledge, is it still ok to SELECT from this table even during the UPDATE? I'm assuming the UPDATE statement hasn't yet "committed" its change so any SELECT's ran during will return the last known committed values? It's not going to lock the reads right and wait for the UPDATE to finish?

I'm thinking to break out the entire operation in a SELECT Id FROM customers in to a temporary table, then cursor loop over the table so that one UPDATE... call is ran and not doing any enormous locks (provided my assumptions about a huge lock above are true).

Comment: MySQL will put a write lock on every record involved in the update.  Not sure if reading still be possible, and Gordon's answer sadly didn't mention anything about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are concerned about *both* the cost of the function and ongoing transactions and locking, then you might want to do this in batches.  If the value is currently `NULL` and the new values are not, then this is easy:

```
UPDATE customers 
    SET AssetsTotal = f_SumAssetCosts(c.Id)
    WHERE AssetsTotal IS NOT NULL
    LIMIT 1000;  -- or whatever
```

This will update a fraction of the customers each time, limiting the locking and the period when the table is not available.

This gets tricky if the value is not starting off as `NULL`.  In that case, you *could* set it to `NULL` . . . somewhat expensive but cheaper than the function call.

There are other methods depending on the specific requirements:

- Add a column to specify if the column has been updated.
- Regenerate the entire table, use `truncate` and re-insert/rename the regenerating table.
- Do all the calculations in another table, use `join` to bring them in, and delete from the other table.

Considerations are:

- Do all the updates have to appear at the same time?
- What is the transactional load?
- How expensive is the function?

Comment: Thanks for the response Gordon. You've given me an idea of adding another column to the table, something like "LastUpdatedTime" so I can do the "IS NOT NULL" equivalent on the data as you said. However, I do have to consider the UPDATE failing and skipping that row and not getting in to an infinite loop. I'm very curious as to what locking is going on though. Even when doing it in chunks, is the lock as harsh as pausing SELECT's or will SELECT's return old 'last committed' data?

Comment: Answered my own question now I've found it in the docs. It depends on the transaction isolation level of the session and whether its InnoDB or MyISAM type tables. For my use (InnoDB), and READ COMMITTED isolation, the SELECT's on the data will succeed even if the UPDATE has a write-lock on the data.

Comment: `LIMIT 1000` will get slow and slower -- as it scans more and more rows that have already been processed.  The solution is to chunk based on the PK.  See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks (but adapt for `UPDATE`).

Comment: Good to see you again @RickJames. I checked out your profile from my previous question yesterday and stumbled across your web-site and found that snippet of chunking on the delete. I've planned to adapt it to what Im doing and wanted to give you credit for it. So thank you :).